# NGINX Reverse Proxy with SignalR and Dynamic DNS Resolution

Tags: c#, .net, nginx, dns, signalr

I have a microservice built in C# (.NET Core 3.1), and i'm using SignalR to allow real-time communication between the front-end app and a feature provided by this microservice.
In the stack, we've another container that runs NGINX as a web server (for the frontend application) and reverse proxy (that provide access to the services).

I've found this post (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/server?view=aspnetcore-3.1#linux-with-nginx) in microsoft documentation,and then to configured the route:

```
location /route/to/signalR/endpoint {
    proxy_pass https://microservice-name:3000/route/to/signalR/endpoint;

    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
    proxy_cache off;
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```

And, up to this point, everything is ok.

But then appeared a defect that after some time nginx started to respond 404 on all requests received. This happened because our microservices containers might stop (due to healthckeck) and then starts again, and it may have a different IP Address.

To solve this issue i followed the instructions of this article: https://medium.com/driven-by-code/dynamic-dns-resolution-in-nginx-22133c22e3ab, which worked fine for the endpoints that didn't use the signalR.

```
#BEFORE
location /some/common/route
{
    proxy_pass https://microservice-name:3000/some/common/route;;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
}

#AFTER
location /some/common/route
{
    set $someCommonRoute https://microservice-name:3000/some/common/route;
    proxy_pass $someCommonRoute;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
}
```

I expected this to work in the signalR route as well, using this configuration:

```
location /route/to/signalR/endpoint {
    set $routeToSignalREndpoint https://microservice-name:3000/route/to/signalR/endpoint;
    proxy_pass $routeToSignalREndpoint;

    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
    proxy_cache off;
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```

But then, this was enough to make the server returns error 400 (Bad request) in this route.
Does someone know why it has happened? How could I configure NGINX to use SignalR and Dynamic DNS Resolution?

Comment: You are getting back a response which means you are finding the host, but may not be getting the rest of the route.  Bad Request normally means the server doesn't like a parameter in the request.  One reason could be the default browser.  Some servers refuse a connection when you use the wrong browser.  So in the c# request you may need to add the UserAgent.  See : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent?force_isolation=true  You can also get a bad request if you are sending the wrong type protocol : HTTP or HTTPS.

Comment: When I passed the hard-coded url as the parameters for the "proxy_pass" everything worked fine. So it's not a problem of http/https nor browser related. This problem only happens when the proxy_pass uses the url through a variable.

Comment: Are you an Admin?  You don't have Admin privilege when running inside VS unless you start VS by right click on shortcut and select Run As Admin.  You may also have a domain issue.  Check with your MIS group to see if the domain is correct.